# Show only exactly unique results in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I need help getting results to be exactly unique. This means that if the record already exist then I don't want it to show at all in the result. I am using MySQL and MySQL Workbench.

Given the tables

Section

```
Course_id   Sec_id  Semester    Year
1234           1    Spring      2010
3456           2    Spring      2010
5678           1    Spring      2010
7890           1    Spring      2010
9012           1    Spring      2010
```

Course

```
Course_id   Name
1234        English
3456        English
5678        Math
7890        Science
9012        Music
```

I have tried the following solution but it shows English in the result, I want to eliminate English altogether as it is offered twice.

```
SELECT 
    s.course_id, c.name, s.year
FROM
    section as s, course as c
WHERE
    s.course_id = c.course_id AND s.year = 2010 AND s.sec_id = 1
```

The result I get from the above query.

```
Course_id   Name    Year
1234        English 2010
5678        Math    2010
7890        Science 2010
9012        Music   2010
```

The result that I want

```
Course_id   Name    Year
5678        Math    2010
7890        Science 2010
9012        Music   2010
```

Comment: `SELECT 
    MAX(s.course_id), c.name,MAX( s.year)
FROM
    section as s, course as c
WHERE
    s.course_id = c.course_id GROUP BY c.name HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.name)=1`

Comment: @Mihai Why would you count DISTINCT? OP doesn't want the duplicated entry. Your condition will include `English` too. Please explain if I mistook the question..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to group the results and pick only group containing 1 row:

```
SELECT 
    s.course_id, c.name, s.year
FROM
    section as s, course as c
GROUP BY
    c.name
HAVING 
    count(c.name) = 1
WHERE
    s.course_id = c.course_id AND s.year = 2010 AND s.sec_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get non-duplicate course ids you can use the following query:

```
SELECT Course_id
FROM course 
GROUP BY Course_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Using the above query as a derived table, you can filter out duplicate courses with an `INNER JOIN` operation:

```
SELECT 
    s.course_id, c.name, s.year
FROM
    section as s
JOIN (
    SELECT Course_id
    FROM course 
    GROUP BY Course_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) as d ON s.course_id = d.course_id
JOIN 
    course as c ON d.course_id = c.d.course_id
WHERE
    s.year = 2010 AND s.sec_id = 1
```